# Apache configuration - MaxClients

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

can someone explaine me more abou MaxClient value? I know that it's about the simultaneus client, but... it mean the request per seconds? PEr minutes? Or maybe all the users that are on the site, even that who doesn't open pages?

Answer (score 1):

From [TFM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#MaxClients):

> The MaxClients directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous
>   requests that will be served.

Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Yes, but what "simultaneous" mean? By seconds? By minutes?

Comment: simultaneous: adjective. happening at the same time

Answer (score 1):

In [eApache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) they describe it clearly (in Apache 2.4 MaxClients is renamed to MaxRequestWorkers):

> The MaxRequestWorkers directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Any connection attempts over the MaxRequestWorkers limit will normally be queued, up to a number based on the ListenBacklog directive. Once a child process is freed at the end of a different request, the connection will then be serviced.

So that's the maximum number of requests your Apache instance can serve. Being on a page may or may not have one or more connections opened, that will depend on what is the web page you are serving: it may be doing some requests in background or it may have an open socket. In case of static content the request starts when the client connects and sends the request and it finishes when the connection is closed (or Apache times it out).

Comment: There is a way for check if my webpage made request in background? My site is build with joomla

Comment: You could use the development tools in your browser to see the connections or use some traffic analyzer like Wireshark of Fiddler.